# How to make li elements the same width while maintaining anchor href functionality

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I begin with the following code below:

```css
#square {
  position: fixed;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 255, 230);
}

ul {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
li {
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
.navlink {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #66DE66;
}
```

```html
<div id = "square">
  <ul>
    <li><a class = "navlink" href = "#">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a class = "navlink" href = "#">Middle</a></li>
    <li><a class = "navlink" href = "#">End</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I need the `li` elements (Introduction, Middle, and End) to be the same width, while remaining centered, and while maintaining anchor `href` functionality and complete hover functionality. I've tried altering the width of the `li` element and `.navlink` class to no avail. I've also tried defining the green rectangular elements under `li` instead of `.navlink`, but that just presented new problems.

I suspect the padding I have defined for my `.navlink` class may present a problem, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with the code the *column flexbox* does not have a *defined height* and its stacking up to *auto* height of the *flex items* (see after removing `margin-top` on `li` and the *relative translation* on the `ul`):

```css
#square {
  position: fixed;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 255, 230);
}

ul {
  /*position: relative;
  bottom: 30px;*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
li {
  /*margin-top: 40px;*/
  text-align: center;
}
.navlink {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #66DE66;
}
```

```html
<div id = "square">
  <ul>
    <li><a class = "navlink" href = "#">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a class = "navlink" href = "#">Middle</a></li>
    <li><a class = "navlink" href = "#">End</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now you can see the `li` taking up as much space as it requires when the  `navlink` anchor element is made a *block element* by adding `display: block`:

```css
#square {
  position: fixed;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 255, 230);
}

ul {
  /*position: relative;
  bottom: 30px;*/
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
li {
  /*margin-top: 40px;*/
  text-align: center;
}
.navlink {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: block; /* added */
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #66DE66;
}
```

```html
<div id = "square">
  <ul>
    <li><a class = "navlink" href = "#">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a class = "navlink" href = "#">Middle</a></li>
    <li><a class = "navlink" href = "#">End</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now you can  make your `ul` and `inline-flex` element so that it takes only *as much space as it needs* and remove `align-items: center`. Also horizontally center the `square` by making it a flexbox too and using `justify-content: center`. Adjust the `margin` between the `li` and there you go:

```css
#square {
  position: fixed;
  width: 350px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(230, 255, 230);
  display: flex; /* made this a flexbox */
  justify-content: center; /* align horizontally */
}

ul {
  /*position: relative;
  bottom: 30px;*/
  display: inline-flex; /* changed to inline flex */
  flex-direction: column;
  /*align-items: center;*/
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  margin-top: 10px; /* changed */
  text-align: center;
}

.navlink {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: block; /* added */
}

a:hover {
  background-color: #66DE66;
}
```

```html
<div id="square">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="navlink" href="#">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a class="navlink" href="#">Middle</a></li>
    <li><a class="navlink" href="#">End</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```